# Why `display:table-cell` make `margin:0 auto` take no effect?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#head{
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">set in middle and center</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rdPN.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Both div head and div main was set as center by `margin:0 auto`,you can see.
I want to set the image in div main as middle vertically.
Just add `display:table-cell` in div main.

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#head{
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">set in middle and center</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rdPN.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Now the image was set as middle vertically,however div main was not  setted as  `margin:0 auto`,why `display:table-cell`  make `margin:0 auto` take no effect?

Comment: Write an actual table and add `margin: 0 auto` to a `td` element. Does that take affect? Same deal here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` on the image with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center it

check this:

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#head{
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main{
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
 
#main img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="head">set in middle and center</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rdPN.png" alt="">
</div>
```